# algorithm to get an unique group id from a combination of element in an integer set

Tags: algorithm

Let's say if I have a row with 3+ attributes A, B, C and other Attrs

```
row1: A=1, B=5, C=10, Other Attrs
row2: A=1, B=5, C=10, Other Attrs
row3: A=2, B=5, C=10, Other Attrs
row4: A=2, B=5, C=10, Other Attrs
row5: A=3, B=6, C=11, Other Attrs
row6: A=3, B=6, C=11, Other Attrs
```

So if I want to assign each row a group ID by combination of A, B, C, row1, row2 have same group id x, row 3 row 4 have group id y, row 5 row 6 have group id z.

A simple solution is:

```
group id = A * S + B * S^2 + C * S^3 (S is the max integer number)
```

But my problem is I need an algorithm to back out each of A, B, C value from group id

for example, I need to be able to back out A=1, B=5, C=10 from group id x solely

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, this would be enough:

```
group id = A + B * S + C * S^2;
```

To get back A, B, and C:

```
A = id % S;

B = (id / S) % S;

C = (id / S^2);
```

Where `/` is integer division and `%` is modulo.

Comment: With the restriction that `A`,`B`,`C` < `S`

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - Of course, `0 <= A, B < S` to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example a much simpler approach would be:

```
a * 10^6 + b*10^3 + c
```

which would give you

```
001005010
001005010
002005010
002005010
003006011
003006011
```

and the inverse of this function is very simple.  If your numbers are possibly longer than 3 digits, adjust accordingly.

Comment: I end up with the solution above but still thanks for the help.